# Does shrinking partitions really improve performance?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, performance

Does shrinking partitions really improve performance? I thought that the OS and applications need a lot of free space to move around for optimum performance.

Comment: Why would you think that shrinking partitions would increase performance?

Comment: On a physical HDD having the OS on the outer (faster) tracks might make a marginal improvement to peak transfer speeds, but the benefit is likely dwarfed by disk latency when seeking between areas. For SSDs there would be no difference at all where on the disk it is reading or writing from, it should all be the same.

Comment: I agree with Mokubai. The only thing I shrink from time to time are machines and that is to keep machines within the constraints I gave them. Otherwise I let data on main host partitions live where it wants.

Comment: An unusual case where I found shrinking a partition helped: A Linux box often found the OS partition had minor corruption, fixed after FSCK. After trying a number of ways to prevent this , I shrunk the *boot* partition a bit, thinking that perhaps BIOS might cause the corruption during boot (admittedly, a strange thought,  but I'd tried almost everything else). Ha! Since then  no corruption. Of course, this has absolutely nothing to do with your question about increasing *performance*, which shrinking is unlikely to affect. Perhaps if you needed space for a swap file, in older Linux...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I would think that by shrinking the partition you excluded a bad sector out of it.

Comment: @harrymc, yes, except the *boot* partition was shrunk, effectively putting a "dead band" between it and the *OS partition*, which was being corrupted, and which I left untouched by gparted.

Comment: Thank you. The recommendation to shrink partitions to enhance performance came from a technical article from a trusted source. The article had recommendations I had not heard before, and those recommendations have since proven useful. Though I thought the OS, applications, and data need room on the drives to grow, 'move around,' and for seeking and reads/writes, I realized that technology can change a lot over time. And since I had missed these other enhancements, perhaps I was wrong. Now I think the trusted source was wrong or didn't explain it fully. Thank you again everyone.

Answer (score -1):

The idea of having small partition to enhance performance is applied in some way on many UNIX systems where the partition is divided in cylinder groups and each time a directory is created, its content is affected to a cylinder group where blocks will be preferably allocated (other groups are used if the default group is full).

Then if you are working heavily in one directory, the head will not have to move much. If a file is growing, this system makes the added blocks not too far away from the other even if the disk is fragmented. But if you work on many directories in the same time, you won’t have increased performances, you may even have lower performance since the head has to travel accros the whole drive.

We have the advantage of small partition, but not the inconvenient of being prevented to add a file while the whole partition is not full.

Comment: Cylinder groups are a fiction published by the disk firmware. The OS usually doesn't know the real physical layout of the HDD, and wouldn't anyway be able to do much with it.